# Unable to load udev rules file

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, rules, udev

After modifying `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-tpm.rules` file, am trying to reload using below commands

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
```

But getting error as below:

```
edge@edge:~$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
Failed to wait for daemon to reply: Connection timed out
```

What is the solution for this?